Which books in the Catholic Old Testament, precede the canonisation of the Hebrew Bible?
Which books in the Catholic Old Testament, precede the canonisation of the Hebrew Bible?
I understand for example that the Books of Macabees isn't part of the Hebrew Bible Canon, but from what I heard, it follows it in time, rather than being rejected from it. So it wouldn't precede it.
I know that the Protestant Old Testament Canon is the same one as Jews use today in their Hebrew Bible, and that the Catholic Old Testament Canon has all that plus extra books.
So i'm wondering if any books in the Catholic Old Testament are so old in origin that they precede the canonisation of the Hebrew Bible / canonisation of the Hebrew Bible used today(which is in the masoretic tradition)?
There is a complexity here also, but one that opens up a possible avenue that help address the question. The Septuagint is so old it even precedes Christianity, and it has a number of books not in the modern Hebrew canon. And furthermore, my understanding is that one skilled in biblical hebrew, and ancient greek, that studies the Septuagint carefully,  sees that the underlying text it is translating is slightly different in some places,  implying that there was a Hebrew version for it.
Further backing that up, my understanding is that in the Judean desert, while there's lots of uniformity, (and particularly uniformity within the Torah),  still there are different versions/variations of text for various Hebrew books of the bible, in places here and there, small variations. And it has been viewed(perhaps by Emmanuel Tov?), as there being  hebrew proto-septuatint and (of course hebrew), proto-masoretic.
Moving from that to books. If there were Hebrew proto-masoretic books not in the masoretic canon of today then perhaps we wouldn't know. But it'd be interesting to know if there are Hebrew proto-septuagint books in the Dead Sea Scrolls /  Scrolls from the Judean Desert?
And perhaps some of those books in greek form might be in the catholic bible, so would fit what i'm asking of any books in the catholic bible that precede the canonisation of the hebrew bible.
But perhaps even without considering the DSS/scrolls of the Judean desert,  there might be an answer to if any books of the Catholic Old Testament are known to precede canonisation of the Hebrew Bible used today?

I suspect, that "canonisation of the Hebrew Bible" is not a well defined (or known) point in time, but a long process. Also the emergence of the biblical books was often a longer process with multiple stages. So the question may be difficult to answer.

@K-HB  good point , some interesting info here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37522/did-the-men-of-the-great-assembly-canonize-tanach  probably a good thing fo rme to look at is oldest deuterocanonical books https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterocanonical_books    has a table. And stuff before Macabees like before 150BCE.. pref even before 170BCE.. there are some there or at least some candidates

Dates of the Apocrypha and their original languages
(Information from The New American Bible: Revised Edition 2012)
The seven Apocryphal books are dated as:

Wisdom of Ben Sirach - 175 B.C.
Wisdom of Solomon - 50 B.C.
Tobit - Early 2nd century B.C.
Judith - 100 B.C.
1st Maccabees - 100 B.C.
2nd Maccabees - After 124 B.C.
Baruch - Unknown

Of these books, only Sirach is known with certainty to have been originally composed in Hebrew. The Greek versions that come down to us begin with a translator's note, describing how his grandfather, Jesus [son of Eleazar, son of Sirach] wrote the book in Hebrew, and that he wanted to translate it into Greek in order to make it accessible to a wider audience. The Hebrew manuscripts were lost to history until the late 19th century, but archeologists have discovered fragments which together give us most of the book in its original Hebrew. Comparison of the Hebrew manuscripts with the Greek text demonstrate that the Greek is an accurate translation and therefore is considered reliable even in those parts where the Hebrew is not preserved.
The Greek language of Baruch seems to be translated from Hebrew or Aramaic, but no evidence of the original manuscripts survives. This is why dating the book is so difficult. The Greek version was probably translated after 200 B.C. but that doesn't help discern when the original version was composed.
Tobit was probably originally written in Aramaic, but only fragments of the Aramaic version have been found.
Judith may have been originally written in Aramaic; Jerome translated a now-lost Aramaic version into the Latin version found in the Vulgate. No Hebrew or Aramaic manuscripts survive.
First Maccabees seems to have originally been written in Hebrew. Jerome and Origen report having access to Hebrew manuscripts, and the Greek text has hallmarks of being a translation from Hebrew. However, no Hebrew manuscripts survive.
The second book of Maccabees and the Wisdom of Solomon were originally composed in Greek. There is no textual or traditional evidence that they are translations of Hebrew or Aramaic.
Canonization of the Old Testament
It is unclear historically exactly when the Jews settled on the canon which they use today, which is also the OT canon used by Protestants. It does not appear to have been decided at one moment, but rather through a process that took centuries. There is no evidence that the Rabbinic tradition of Judaism ever considered books outside the present canon as canonical, and some which are included were at one point disputed (Esther, Song of Solomon, Ecclesiastes). The Jewish enumeration gives 24 books in the OT (counting the twelve minor prophets as one, Ezra-Nehemiah as one, 1-2 Samuel as one, 1-2 Kings as one, and 1-2 Chronicles as one).
The Wisdom of Ben Sirach gives us the earliest evidence of the canon of the Old Testament, as Jesus ben Sirach cites stories from the Old Testament, in order, from the Torah until Nehemiah [Sirach ch.44-50]. Most of the books of our Hebrew Bibles are referenced in this section, and he does not mention any stories outside of the canonical scriptures except his own contemporary Simeon son of Jochanan (50:1). He does not mention Ruth, Esther, or Daniel, which doesn't prove that he considered these books were non-canonical, but there is no contemporaneous evidence that these were considered canonical yet.
Josephus (late 1st century) also provides early evidence as to the Jewish canon. He says that none of the books written since the time of Artaxerxes are considered of equal authority with the ones written before, because the prophetic word had ceased at that time (Against Apion 1.41, quoted in Grudem, Systematic Theology ch.37). Similarly, 1st Maccabees 9:27 indicates that the prophets had ceased a long time prior to the 2nd century B.C., and 14:41 indicates that the Jews in that time period were awaiting the coming of another prophet (perhaps with some eschatological connotations). Josephus also enumerates the OT scriptures as 22 books, but without a complete list. It is possible that he divided the books differently, or that he omitted some of the books that are now considered canonical. According to traditional understanding, all the books now considered canonical were written by the time of Artaxerxes, though modern scholarship dates Esther and parts of other books (esp. Daniel and Ezra-Nehemiah) to later.
Early tradition associates the compilation of the canon with Nehemiah, Ezra, and Judas Maccabeus. Second Maccabees 2:13 tells of Nehemiah gathering the sacred writings. These were scattered during the war with Antiochus IV Epiphanes, but re-gathered by Judas Maccabeus (2nd Macc. 2:14).
The late 1st century A.D. Latin Apocypse of Ezra (a.k.a. 2 Esdras or 4 Esdras) attributes the creation of the canon to Ezra. Chapter 14:19-48 tells how, when the Scriptures had been totally destroyed, God empowered Ezra and five other men to rewrite them from memory. Verse 45 also gives the enumeration of 24, agreeing with the Rabbinic accounting, but there is no list so we can't be sure the canon that the author of this book had in mind is the same as the present one. There is record in the Mishnah of disputations about Ecclesiastes and Song of Solomon persisting into the 1st century.
The oldest complete record of the OT canon is actually from a Christian source, namely bishop Melito of Sardis writing in about 170 A.D. His list is identical to the one used today by Jews and Protestants, except that Esther is missing. In the 4th century, Athanasius lists the canon for the Old and New Testaments (34th festal epistle), with a list identical to the Protestant canon except that he includes Baruch and excludes Esther. However, other ancient Christian sources do treat Apocryphal books as Scripture (see for example 1st Clement 55:4). Origen's canon list (early 3rd century) includes the Epistle of Jeremiah and at least one book of Maccabees. Starting in the end of the fourth century, one finds many authors expressly arguing that some or all of the Apocrypha should be considered canon. Most famously, Augustine argued for precisely the canon used by Catholics today.
Summary: Putting all this together, it seems that the canon was mostly decided by the 2nd century B.C., and therefore the entire Apocrypha was composed after the canon was decided, with the possible exception of Baruch. However, disputes about Ecclesiastes, Song of Solomon, Esther, and Baruch persisted into the 1st century A.D. and beyond.

Note about Dead Sea Scrolls: Many books of the Apocrypha have been found among the Dead Sea Scrolls, however this does not imply that the Qumran community viewed them as canonical. I am sure that we all have many books in our libraries that we don't consider canonical. Even in our Bibles, there are introductions and translator's notes that no-one would think are canonical.
Given the large number of copies found among the Dead Sea Scrolls of 1st Enoch and the Book of Jubilees, it's possible that they thought these works were canonical. However, no list of the canon has been found at Qumran, so this is only speculation.

Cool to know, Personally I like the book of Sirach. It's also included in my Bible. :)

I also really like Sirach, but of course that's not a good reason to consider it canonical ;)

My church considers the Deuterocanonical books as part of the Bible. So... Sirach is part for us.
